# Software for creating digital images from an album and captioning them

Tags: software-recommendations, photo

I'm looking for software to create digital versions of and caption individual photos from albums and paper prints. Can anyone suggest any products that might do this?

Comment: Might I suggest Irfanview. Can be used for annotating photos & documents

Comment: IrfanView can connect to a scanner and images can be edited but individual prints usually have to be rotated and you have to guess the angle  to straighten them - the preview box doesn't give enough resolution to do it accurately. Then you have to define a cropping box and add the required text if you want to add a caption. A lot of work!

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is an awfully broad requirement -- can you narrow it down at all?

Answer (score 1):

Affinity Publisher is pretty intuitive- create a page, create a picture box, or a text box, then place or resize or superimpose whichever of these, drag and drop photo or text from desktop or file, then export to various formats. If also have Affinity Photo then can edit photo within same window.

If on a Mac, then Mac preview allows more limited adding text, boxes, arrows etc to a photo, then export similarly as jpeg, pdf etc.

Answer (score -1):

There is a review of software for this purpose on [HubPages](https://turbofuture.com/graphic-design-video/Whats-the-Best-Multiple-Photo-Scanning-Software). [Caption Pro](https://captionpro.com.au:444/AlekaConsulting/index.php/caption-photos/) seems to work OK.